# Django time limit for votting

Tags: django

I have a voting application, how can I set time limits so that I can vote for a limited amount of time, after which the poll will close?

models.py

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()
    option_one = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    option_two = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    option_three = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    option_one_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    option_two_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    option_three_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def total(self):
        return self.option_one_count + self.option_two_count + 
      self.option_three_count
```

views.py

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreatePollForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect ('home')

    else:   
        form = CreatePollForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'poll/create.html', context)


def vote(request, poll_id):
    poll = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_option = request.POST['poll']
        if selected_option == 'option1':
            poll.option_one_count += 1
        elif selected_option == 'option2':
            poll.option_two_count += 1
        elif selected_option == 'option3':
            poll.option_three_count += 1
        else:
            return HttpResponse(400, 'Invalid form')
        poll.save()
        return redirect('results', poll.id)    
    context = {'poll':poll}
    return render(request, 'poll/vote.html', context)
```

Comment: Please share the view where you are voting.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem add the views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only pseudo code / and thoughts but it will point you in the right direction.

Your model will want to include:

- `active_from` field which is a datetime.
- `active_for` field which will be the duration a vote is open (maybe seconds).

You can then do some basic maths to work out if a poll should be active.

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return (datetime.datetime.now() - self.active_from).seconds > active_for
```

In your view you can now use the model instance to make view edits.

In your vote function you can do something like:

```
def vote(request, poll_id):
    poll = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if poll.is_active:
            # Do logic around counting a vote
        else:
            # Do vote closed logic
    ...
```

In your template you will be able to use the property in the django templating syntax, it will be something like this:

```
{% if poll.is_active %}
```